# How to exclude a group of hotstrings for a group of programs?

Tags: autohotkey

I use a combination of [`#IfWinNotActive`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) and [`GroupAdd`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GroupAdd.htm) but it doesn't work:

```
GroupAdd, GroupName, ahk_exe Notepad++.exe
GroupAdd, GroupName, ahk_exe Obsidian.exe
GroupAdd, GroupName, ahk_exe Code.exe
GroupAdd, GroupName, ahk_exe ImageGlass.exe
#IfWinNotActive ahk_group GroupName
    ::->::→
    ::--::–
    :*:(::() {Left 2}
    ;~ :*:'::'' {Left 2}
    :*:"::"" {Left 2}
    :*:[::{[ 2}{bs}}{]} {Left 2}
    :*:{::{{ 2}{bs}{}} {Left 2}
    :*:===::{Enter}===================={Enter}
    :*:__-::____________________
return
```

One person wonders about the [the auto-execute section problem](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto). But apparently if there are hotstrings the script should be in persistent mode? I also explicitly add `#Persistent` but it doesn't work too. It does work in a standalone script.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine, are you sure the GroupAdd lines ever get ran?
I'd guess they're not in your [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto).

Comment: hmm, but apparently if there are hotstrings the script should be in persistent mode? I also explicitly add `#Persistent` but it doesn't work too. It does work in a standalone script

Comment: `#Persistent` shouldn't be relevant to this in any way. But yes, a script that has hotstrings will be persistent by default. Doesn't matter if you specify it yourself. But can you show the full script that you're unable to get working?